# YouTube Data API v3 Queries Per Day quota issue

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For years we have used the YouTube search API to provide a simple YouTube fallback for smart-tvs with no native YouTube app available. The Queries Per Day for our registered app has been set to "unlimited" trough all this time AFAIK, and we only use the youtube.search-list API.
Suddenly, three weeks back, access to the search function was no longer working. Turns out the quota for daily queries was set to blank(no number, no nothing). When trying to change it we get "enter a number in the range 0 to ."

First of all we linked the app to a billing account to be able to adjust the quota. But it was still not working. Then we contacted YouTube and filled out a big form to increase the quota. We got reply from YouTube that the quota request was granted. But we are still not able to set/change the quota. I've tried replying to to quota mail, but I guess the mail is not monitored.

We see others have had similar issues, and the solution seems to have been to contact YouTube. But we have not found any way to contact them regarding YouTube data API support queries except here on stackoverflow(we do not have a paid support plan). So we're posting here hoping that anyone from YouTube can respond - or to get tips from users that have been in the same situation.

UPDATE:
We have now tried two things:
* Removing and adding back in YouTube data API v3 in the registered app. Did not help
* Activating YouTube data API v3 on another app we have registered - this gave us a daily quota of 10000(but we would definatly prefer not to have to change to another API key)

UPDATE 2:
Info we left out that might be relevant. We recently went trough a process with Google filling out the "YouTube API Services Form"(a google docs form). We went back and forth with the google team, replacing logos, adding ToS links, changing UI etc. until we got a:
"Thanks for your response to the Audit Form. We will  conduct our audit based on the information you provided.  We will notify you if additional information is needed or when we completed our review. Thank you for your cooperation."
After this we have heard nothing.

Today we can see that the quota is back to 10000... We did send a second request for quota raise and I also sent a mail to the Audit Form team. Not sure which one did the trick - have received no response. And that's probably the most annoying thing about this - the complete lack of feedback.

Comment: You have to check your email. Your access to the API must have been disabled.

Comment: Thanks goblin, but we have checked any connected mailbox, spam-folders, deleted etc etc. All we find is a message from July stating that google have upped our daily quota.

Comment: I posted my answer below based on what I experienced before. Your project might be mistakenly disabled. You may need to resubmit the form to get your access back.

Comment: @OtrumAS I am facing same issue. If i link Billing details then is it works or not? Also i filled that long form but no any reply from youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same issue before in one of my projects and I can tell that your access to Youtube data api has been disabled.

TLDR;

I noticed this first because I got the error below when calling Youtube data API.

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "accessNotConfigured", "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project <my_project_id> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=<my_project_id> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.", "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=<my_project_id>" } ]
```

So I went to the console and checked if the API is enabled (And it was). Then I checked the quota, which I suspect is the issue because I got a blank value in the queries per day. I could still edit the value, but those values didn't take effect. It eventually transitioned to 0 and after that, I can no longer edit it (This is after some editing and refresh).

When I looked at my email, it shows that they sent me an email with the following subject and content.

> Subject: [FYI] YouTube disabled your inactive project’s access to YouTube Data API Service
>
> Dear YouTube API Developer,
>
> According to our records, your project has been inactive for the past 90 consecutive days. In accordance with the YouTube API Services Developer Policies (link), we disabled your project’s access to and use of the YouTube Data API Service.
>
> This will not affect other Google API Services that you may have enabled on this project.
>
> For reference, your inactive project number is *my_project_number*
>
> If you desire to access and use YouTube Data API Service, or believe you were disabled in error, you may complete and submit this form to get in touch with us.
>
> Thanks,
>
> YouTube API Services team

The form was included in the email, but since you haven't received one, here's what you need to do as stated [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues//141187677#comment2).

> If the API is indeed enabled, then this means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.
>
> You should’ve received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain the project’s access. But just in case you missed it, please fill out and submit the exceptions form below:
>   https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en

The alternative, outright solution is to create a new project where you will get the default 10,000 quota.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! We actually left out what might have been important info regarding the Youtube API services form. We will update the original post!

Comment: I use 10k quota in about 2 hours on a live stream. just monitoring a chat, in a very efficient way.. what the heck is up with that? They wont even take my money can i just get 50k or something for a fiver.. jeez (then i have 10 youtube pages open with chat no problem)